# What is difference with TCPClient: Client.Connected & Client.Client.Connected?

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

If someone with some expertise can chime in here on the difference here:

```
Dim tClient as New TCPClient

tClient.Connect(xxx, xxx)
```

..and:

```
tClient.Client.Connect(xxx,xxx)
```

I do not know which one to use?

Comment: `TcpClient.Connect()` calls `[Socket].Connect()` (so, `TcpClient.Client.Connect()`, since `Client` is the Socket object) after some validations, which include the creation of the Socket is it's null, verifying whether IpV6 can be used, the Address of the EndPoint if a hostname is specifed etc. The Socket.Connect() method does the rest: e.g., it checks whether `isListening` is true and throws if it is...

Comment: The title and the body of your question are asking about two different things. In the title, you seem to be asking about the `.Connected` property, while in the body, you compare the two different calls to the `Connect()` method.

Comment: As Jimi said, if you look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,7f451440390e3925), `TcpClient.Connect()` does the dirty work for you (because TcpClient is a wrapper around the `Socket` class), _and then_ calls `.Client.Connect()`. If you want to use the latter, you'd have to do all the dirty work yourself; in which case, you might as well use the `Socket` class directly.

Comment: As to the `Connected` property. `TcpClient.Connected` simply [returns](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,22efae515d6f014f) `.Client.Connected` so you could use either one if you want but really there's no reason to use the latter.

Comment: @ 41686d6564: Thank you for noticing the OP said "Connected" in the title ... then then asked about "Connect" in his post.  Two completely different things :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client
>
> **TcpClient.Client Property**
>
> Gets or sets the underlying Socket.

In other words, you generally want:

```
Dim tClient as New TCPClient
tClient.Connect(xxx, xxx)
```

... OR ...

```
Dim tClient As New TcpClient(xxx, xxx)
```

Comment: This is to initially connect to the server.  So when do you use tClient.Client.Connect?

Comment: Read the documentation!  "TCPClient" is a (higher-level) VB.Net object.  It wraps the underlying (lower-level) socket objects.  The TCPClient object also exposes a "Client" property, which gives you access to the underlying, lower-level socket object.  If you ever need it.  You typically want to code to the higher level object "TCPClient".  Best case: using "tClient.Client.Connect" is perverse, but harmless.  Worst case: it will leave parts of the wrapper object uninitialized, and Bad Things could happen.